# What's causing "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'"

Tags: sql

```
USE VHT_RPT

SELECT 
    [QueueName] AS QueueName, Interval,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), Interval, 103) AS DATEPART,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), Interval, 108) AS TIMEPART,
    COUNT(CALLID) AS Callbacks
FROM
    (SELECT             
         [QueueName] AS QueueName,
         DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(HOUR, '1970-01-01', InTimestart) * 60 + FLOOR(DATEPART(MINUTE, InTimeStart) / 15) * 15, '1970-01-01') AS Interval,
         CALLID 
     FROM 
         QDump 
     WHERE 
         InResult IN ('I2',  -- ASAP callback
                      'I5',  -- Scheduled callback
                      'I8',  -- Web ASAP Callback
                      'I9',  -- Web scheduled callback
                      'I18', -- Second Chance callback
                      'I25', -- After Hours scheduled callback
                      'I32', -- Virtual Queue ASAP callback
                      'I33'  -- Date Book scheduled callback))
        AS Sub,
WHERE
    interval BETWEEN '05/03/2021' AND '05/08/2021' -- Date Format is "MM-DD-YYYY"
GROUP BY 
    Interval, [QueueName]
ORDER BY 
    Interval
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? SQL Server? Most likely the problem is the comma after 'AS Sub'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is simple ->

```
 'I33'  -- Date Book scheduled callback))
```

Should be ->

```
'I33'  -- Date Book scheduled callback
))
```

And you need to lose the comma after your alias.

```
AS Sub,
```

Becomes

```
AS Sub
```